# Python: Difference in iteration over tuple and list in list-comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, list-comprehension

My goal: Understand why the following function "change" behaves differently for the inputs "list of a single tuple" and "tuple of a single tuple".

I use the list comprehension in "change" in a different program and was surprised to find that the two inputs behaved differently.

```
def change(entries):
    return ['\t'.join(entry) for entry in entries]

entry_tuple_list = [('val1', 'val2')]
print(change(entry_tuple_list)) #Evaluates to ['val1\tval2']

entry_tuple_tuple = (('val1', 'val2')) 
print(change(entry_tuple_tuple)) #Evaluates to ['v\ta\tl\t1', 'v\ta\tl\t2']

expected_result = ['val1\tval2']
```

I would have expected **both** `entry_tuple_list` and `entry_tuple_tuple` to display the same behaviour in the function and turn into the `expected_result` of `['val1\tval2']`.

That is not the case as you can see in the code-comments. 
Why do these two inputs cause different outputs?

Comment: [Single element tuples require comma](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-tuple-single-empty/) otherwise it's not a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this `(())` doesnt mean you have `2 tuples`. Let us understand what is happening here:

this `entry_tuple_tuple[0]` will output `val1`

while this `entry_tuple_list[0]` will output `('val1', 'val2')`

so what's wrong here? Indeed in python if you want to have a tuple then you should have `,`.

In here for instance, `a = (12)` is an integer and not a tuple as you would expect. to make it a tuple you can do this `a = 12,`. now `a` is a tuple, and guess what! you don't even need `()`.

To solve your problem, just add `,` as here: `entry_tuple_tuple = (('val1', 'val2'),)`. That should get you nested tuples as you want. I hope you get it by now.

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't aware that the tuple-syntax can be that tricky, that clears it up. I was about to ask if you might perhaps be aware as to why a = (12) does not evaluate to a tuple... then I realized that would mean everything you put some brackets around for human readability would then change into a tuple and answered my own question.

Comment: exactly, ```()``` there are just telling that hey you there, this may be a tuple!

Answer (score 1):

Because your `entry_tuple_tuple = (('val1', 'val2'))` is not a tuple of tuples.  To let python know you want a one-element tuple, slip in a comma, i.e. changing that line to `entry_tuple_tuple = (('val1', 'val2'),)` produces the expected result.

As it stands, it is just picking up  a single tuple with two values.  Your comprehension is iterating over the characters in each of those two values.

Comment: Thanks ! The tuple syntax in this case wasn't quite what I expected it to be, thanks for clearing that up for me !